# Why can't I use left hand assignment to modify value of function result?

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator

I'm trying to assign a value to the what the function return to me. I know this may sounds dumb at first glance but what I'm accomplishing is getting direct reference to alert (In C++, this is called as lvalues) and modify it.

```
function foo() {
  return alert;
}

foo() = "zoo"
```

Well,

```
var name = "alert";
var ref = (reference) => reference.split('.').reduce((o,i)=>o[i], window)

ref(name) = new Proxy(ref(name), {
    apply: (target, thisArg, args) => {

        console.log(thisArg)
        console.log(args)
    
        return "Alert called";
    }
});
```

I could do for now,

```
var name = "alert";    
window[name] = new Proxy(window[name], window), {
    apply: (target, thisArg, args) => {

        console.log(thisArg)
        console.log(args)
    
        return "Alert called";
    }
});
```

But it get complicated with complex objects like `"HTMLCollection.prototype"`

Even with eval, it doesn't work

```
var name = "alert";

eval(name) = new Proxy(eval(name), {
    apply: (target, thisArg, args) => {

        console.log(thisArg)
        console.log(args)
    
        return "Alert called";
    }
});
```

Comment: No. Functions return values, not variables nor references. Assigning a value to a value makes no sense.

Comment: You have the wrong idea about assignment here. `alert()` is a method of the `window` object and that method does not return a value. That's what your code attempts to do, reference the return value of the `alert()` method. If you want direct access to the `alert` functionality, you'd need to write something like `const foo = window.alert`, and this would essentially be a way of caching the alert functionality. But, what's the benefit of doing that here?

Comment: @jeffbRTC So you're trying to use `Proxy` with the string name of arbitrary objects? I still can't think of a good reason to do this, but if that's your only goal and you control input, you can always use `eval`. `eval` is clearly evil, but there are circumstances where it's the cleanest solution, even after you deal with sanitization.

Comment: @DaveNewton Correct. But you still need a direct reference then assign it to a proxy so in this case not even eval works, browser throw an error, left hand assignment ...

Comment: You *can* do something like `assign('foo.bar', new Proxy(...))`, where the function `assign` internally unrolls the dotted object name up to the penultimate nested object, and does `o[i] = proxy` for the last level. You can’t do assignment to variable variables (which is what you’re really asking) any other way.

Comment: @deceze Yes, I expected something like this.

Comment: So, `ref(name) = o` is fundamentally barking up the wrong tree. Do you understand how to implement an `assign(name, o)`, or do you need help with that?

Comment: @deceze No. assign works. I just didn't know that one ....

Comment: @deceze Actually, I tried assign just now. It doesn't work. For example,   Object.assign(alert, "oo")

Comment: @deceze I know it may weird. I just my mind thought it would work..

Comment: @jeffbRTC I'm not sure what you mean--using eval like your snippet makes no sense. You eval the *entire thing*; your snippet just does what you were trying to do before.

Comment: @DaveNewton I need to get the reference to actual alert. When I eval it, it get me that and I don't invoke alert() at all just eval(alert)

Comment: @DaveNewton FYI, I'm trying to solve this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997638/why-do-i-cant-proxy-the-original-function-through-a-reference-variable

Comment: @jeffbRTC ... `eval(``${s} = new Proxy(${s}, { apply: () => console.log("ohai") })``)` I can't make SO parse this right, but that's what I meant.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hell yeah...

Comment: @jeffbRTC Noting that this introduces a host of other problems, e.g., your code isn't code anymore, it's a string. This may or may not be "bad", e.g., there are all sorts of code generation reasons something like this might make sense. Although I'm ... skeptical. I still don't see why you need to do any of this though. If you're trying to do some sort of global/arbitrary AOP thing it's probably better to use existing JS OOP mechanisms. But it's not clear what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much asking for *variable variables*, i.e. resolving variables for assignment by name, and that is only possible in very very limited capacity in Javascript. The only time you can use it is when assigning an object property where the property name is dynamic:

```
foo[bar] = baz;
```

Functions return *values*, not references nor variables, so assigning to the return value of a function is a complete non-starter.

You're *somewhat* on the right track with this:

> ```
> (reference) => reference.split('.').reduce((o,i)=>o[i], window)
> ```

It resolves a dotted name to a value, but again, you cannot *assign* to that resolved value. When a function does `return alert`, it returns **the value `alert` refers to**, which is something like `function () { ... }`. So what you're trying to do is equivalent to:

```
function () { ... } = new Proxy(...)
```

And that just doesn't work. You cannot `return` a "name", you can only return the value the name refers to.

Your function would have to return the *parent* object of the one you're looking for, and you can then assign to a property of it, e.g.:

```
ref(foo)[bar] = baz;
```

This would be equivalent to, e.g.:

```
window['alert'] = new Proxy(...)
```

I.e., setting a property `alert` on the object that `window` refers to. And that obviously works just fine.

Since the above use of the `ref` function is somewhat awkward, the best you can do it wrap that into a function like this:

```
assign(foo, baz)
```

That could look something like this:

```
function assign(name, obj) {
    const path = name.split('.');
    const parent = path.slice(0, -1).reduce((o, i) => o[i], window);
    parent[path[path.length - 1]] = obj;
}

const name = 'foo.bar.baz';
assign(name, new Proxy(ref(name), { ... }));
```

Note that the object in question must be available as a property on `window` though (or some other root object that you could pass into `assign`); there's no (sane) way to assign to a `let` or `const` or any local function variable in this manner.

E.g. this could work:

```
let foo = { bar: {} };
assign('bar', new Proxy(...), foo);
```

This just ain't happening:

```
let foo = {};
assign('foo', new Proxy(...));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was thinking in terms of C++ when asking this question because In C++ it's possible to do what I ask with lvalues and I guess Javascript different....

Comment: Yeah, don't confuse Javascript with C.